# Spring JPA - Best practice to avoid Unique Index constraint (DataIntegrityViolationException) in multithreaded application

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to create method findOrCreate that will get entity or create it in DB. But sometimes another thread create this row between select and insert and Unique Index constraint happens.
In that case I just want select row that was created in another thread.

I searched for answers, but there are many approaches and I can't find best solution.

I decide to create row in separate transaction and forget about exceptions in it.

Here is Java code that I decided to use Spring:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Domain findOrCreate(String name) {
        Domain domain = domainRepo.findByName(name).orElse(null);
        if (domain != null) return domain;
        try {
            domain = self.createAndSave(name);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Exception when creating domain. Looking for existing row.", ex);
        }
        if (domain == null) {
            domain = domainRepo.findByName(name).orElse(null);
            if (domain != null) log.info("Domain found after creating error.");
        }
        return domain;
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Domain createAndSave(String name) {
        try {
            Domain result = create(name);
            domainRepo.saveAndFlush(result);
            return result;
        }catch (Exception ex){
            log.warn("[{}] createAndSave error:{}", name, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Is it right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution of creating the row in a separate transaction and ignoring any exceptions that may occur can work, but it's not the best approach. It can lead to data inconsistency if the row is created in one transaction but not visible in another transaction due to isolation levels or other factors.

A better solution to handle the scenario where another thread creates the row between the select and insert operations is to use the `MERGE` operation in JPA. The `MERGE` operation will insert a new entity if it does not exist in the database, or update the existing entity if it does exist.

Here's an example of how you can use `MERGE` to implement the `findOrCreate` method:

```
@Transactional
public Domain findOrCreate(String name) {
    Domain domain = domainRepo.findByName(name).orElse(null);
    if (domain != null) {
        return domain;
    } else {
        domain = createAndSave(name);
        return domain;
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Domain createAndSave(String name) {
    Domain domain = new Domain(name);
    try {
        domain = entityManager.merge(domain);
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        log.warn("Failed to create domain: {}", name);
        domain = domainRepo.findByName(name).orElse(null);
    }
    return domain;
}
```

In this example, the `findOrCreate` method first checks if the domain exists in the database using the `findByName` method of the `DomainRepository`. If it exists, it returns the domain. Otherwise, it calls the `createAndSave` method to create and save the domain.

The `createAndSave` method creates a new `Domain` object with the specified name, and then uses the `merge` method of the `EntityManager` to insert or update the entity in the database. If the `merge` operation fails with a `PersistenceException`, it means that another transaction has created the entity between the `findByName` and `merge` operations, so the method retrieves the entity from the database using the `findByName` method of the `DomainRepository`.

By using `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation for the `createAndSave` method, a new transaction is created for the `merge` operation, which is isolated from the transaction of the `findOrCreate` method. This ensures that any exceptions that occur in the `merge` operation do not affect the transaction of the `findOrCreate` method.

Note that the `merge` operation may have unexpected side effects if the `Domain` entity has relationships to other entities that are not loaded. In such cases, it may be necessary to first load the entity with all its relationships before calling `merge`.

Comment: As I understand, merge will execute select and update/insert on result of select. In normal situation double selectitng will be unnecessary overhead...